# org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem not found with PySpark in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I want to read data from s3 with PySpark in my laptop. But I am getting the error message below.

```
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", "...")
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", "...")
my_df = spark.read.csv("s3n://bucket-name/file_name.csv").count()
```

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o498.csv.
>   : java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem not found

Comment: Were you able to solve this?  currently driving me nuts

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue. I used the following

```
Spark: 2.4.4
Hadoop: 2.7.3
Haddop-AWS: hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar
AWS-JAVA-SDK: aws-java-sdk-1.7.3.jar
Scala: 2.11
```

Works for me and use `s3a://bucket-name/`

(**Note**: For PySPark I used `aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar`) because I wasn't able to use

```
df.write.csv(path=path, mode="overwrite", compression="None")
```

Use:

```
my_df = spark.read.csv("s3a://bucket-name/file_name.csv").count()
```

Comment: What do you mean you "used the following"? How did you make sure pyspark was pointed at those JARS?